# Fatal error: Call to a member function join() on a non-object?

Tags: magento, join, fatal-error

I'm building a slideshow and I'm trying to join my slideshow table and my images table through this function unfortunately i'm getting this error :

"Fatal error: Call to a member function join() on a non-object"

here's the code :

```
$diaporama = Mage::getModel('diaporama/diaporama')->getCollection();
$diaporama->join(array('images' => 'diaporama/images'), 'main_table.id = images.id', array('*'))
    ->setOrder('position','asc');

$diaporama->load();
return $diaporama ;
```

Does someone see where I'm wrong ?

---

Update :
Ok, now my first problem is solved, I've successfully displayed data on my block. I may still have a problem with my query as i've only got the first image data of my slideshow.
knowing that i've got 2 tables :

**Diaporama :**
- id
- title
- desctiprion

**Diaporama_Images :**
- id
- src
- alt
- title
- description
- position
- diaporama_id (fk)

the result i'm trying to have is something like that

```
diaporama = array(
    'id'
    'title'
    'description'
    'images' => array (
        array(
            'id' => '',
            'title' => '',
            'description' => '',
            'src' => '',
            'alt' => '',
            'position' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '',
            'title' => '',
            'description' => '',
            'src' => '',
            'alt' => '',
            'position' => ''
        )

    )
)
```

and at the moment i'm still far from it.

---

Update 2

I've updated my code that way :

```
$diaporama = Mage::getModel('diaporama/diaporama')->getCollection();
$diaporama->join(array('images' => 'diaporama/images'), 
          'main_table.id=images.diaporama_id', array('*'))
                ->setOrder('position','asc')
                ->load();
return $diaporama;
```

But I'm still missing Diaporama table fields.
Here's my current result with random images as sample data
I'm still missing the diaporama table fields data here's the result with just random images found on internet

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'Un superbe Yacht' (length=16)
      'description' => string 'La description d'un superbe Yacht' (length=33)
      'src' => string 'http://aboutyacht.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/12_diaporama-980x360.jpg' (length=76)
      'alt' => string 'yacht1' (length=6)
      'position' => string '1' (length=1)
      'diaporama_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'Yacht Interieur' (length=15)
      'description' => string 'L'interieur d'un super Yacht' (length=28)
      'src' => string 'http://aboutyacht.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/1_diaporama-980x360.jpg' (length=75)
      'alt' => string 'interieur yacht' (length=15)
      'position' => string '2' (length=1)
      'diaporama_id' => string '1' (length=1)`
```

---

Final edit : Problem solved.

Last update was not working, it was just getting all the images of my table so I finally forgot about the join() method and I solved it that way :

```
$diaporama = Mage::getModel('diaporama/diaporama')->load($id);
$images = Mage::getResourceModel('diaporama/images_collection')
       ->addFieldToSelect('*')
       ->addFieldToFilter('diaporama_id', $id)
       ->setOrder('position','asc')
       ->load();

return array( 'diaporama' => $diaporama, 
              'images' => $images );
```

Thai way i have my slideshow and images assigned sorted by display position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your collection returns null. Why don't you var_dump($diaporama) before the join. Also check system.log and your apache logs, to give us more information. maybe the path to the model you are trying to instantiate cant be found

UPDATE:

Well you are joining main table id into iamges table id. You are seeing result out of pure luck. You are not joining on your forigen key 'main_table.id = images.diaporama_id ' should be it ?

Comment: You're right a var dump game me false. I've found the problem in my config.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, you were right, I updated it that way and now i've got all my images but still missing diaporama fields

Comment: No problem give me my first answered question then :D

Comment: Done, it'd just be cool if you'd a last advise about my last problem :)

Comment: Oh i thought it worked. What is the result, that you are receiving?
If the result from your query is false. Can you please try the query but edit to  array('images.*'). I just want to see if the problem is some sql error, because you have duplicated column names ( 'id')

Comment: I'm good for the images but still missing the diaporama table fields data

Comment: Can you explecictly type, in the array('*') the name of the fields you want to retrive like that - array('title,description, images.id, ... etc');

Comment: I did it but no change in results to notice

Comment: But the resulted collection is just fine u have the ids and u have title and description and img src. Whats the problem ?

Comment: That's true, i can use the result i have. I'm just missing the title and description of the diaporama table.

Comment: Finally it was not working, so I did it another way. see in main post edit :) Ty for your help anyway.